# Javax CriteriaBuilder select Expression by Predicate

Tags: java, jpa

I don't understand is it possible for me to apply "if-else" statement between two expressions:

```
public Predicate build(CriteriaBuilder builder, Root<Person> root) {
    Expression<BigDecimal> value_a_1 = root.get(value_a_1);
    Expression<BigDecimal> value_a_2 = root.get(value_a_2);
    Expression<BigDecimal> value_b_1 = root.get(value_b_1);
    Expression<BigDecimal> value_b_2 = root.get(value_a_2);

    // Here I want to check if one of the _b values is null or 0 (I hope it is correct):
    Expression<Boolean> isValueNullOrZero = builder.or(
            value_b_1.isNull(), value_b_1.in(BigDecimal.ZERO),
            value_b_2.isNull(), value_b_2.in(BigDecimal.ZERO));

    // And then I want to do something like this:
    Expression<BigDecimal> value_c_1 = isValueNullOrZero ? value_a_1 : value_b_1;
    Expression<BigDecimal> value_c_2 = isValueNullOrZero ? value_a_2 : value_b_2;

    // etc
...
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to return `value_c_1, value_c_2` from your query? If so, `CriteriaBuilder.selectCase()` is what you want

Comment: I will have to apply additional conditions on it (sum, gt, le etc) with the other fields.

Comment: Well, the result of `selectCase()` is an `Expression`, so you should be able to use it as a building block for other statements. Never tried it, though